# Required field in PhoneTextBox toolkit component

Tags: windows-phone-8, silverlight-toolkit

I have some PhoneTextBox and their values can't be null. So are REQUIRED. Is There a simple method to do that like in Android?

Comment: http://mobileworld.appamundi.com/blogs/petevickers/archive/2011/02/20/validating-text-boxes-in-windows-phone-7.aspx refer this link

Comment: othervise you can check condition like if(textboxname.Text=="") {}

Comment: I had also thought to the last solution. But in android when an input text is required show an advertise on the input box. I would like something like this, without messagebox..